# Am I allowed to modify figures of a dissertation for my dissertation

Tags: citations, copyright, graphics

Can I modify a figure of someone else's dissertation and use the modified picture in my dissertation? Or might this be a problem regarding the copyright? Of course I would cite the source which I got the picture from in the form:
Picture_X (Own figure based on [Mr. X, 2020])

Comment: What sort of modification? Different data? Different formatting? Those are not the same thing.

Comment: Well it is a picture of a building that contains several devices (dishwasher, tumble dryer, air conditioner etc.). I would like to replace one of the devices by another one that I have drawn on my own because it fits better to my topic

Comment: Better to use the "concept" behind the figure and create your own from scratch.

Comment: You could also contact the author directly to see where they got the image.  If it's in the public domain, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think the author created the image by himself, so it is not public domain.

Comment: usually there is a copyright statement at the start of a dissertation so you can check who owns it.